# Taking a SQL Database with me for a presentation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, portability

I am a beginner with sql and tomorrow I have to turn in my first assignment, which is a simple, small database. The thing is I don't really know if I can just find the database in my computer, copy it in a usb drive and then just plug it in another pc so it can run there. 
Can you please tell me if that's the way it works or if I should do something else?
Thanks a lot.

By the way, I use sql server express 2012. If you need to know anything else, just ask. :)

Comment: Doesn't your teacher specify what format to hand it in? It's probably by taking a backup file (and producing a .BAK) but how would any of us know what your teacher expects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fan of *Attaching* and *Detaching* databases as this leaves no backup on the localdisk but rather just use `BackUp` and `Restore` feature.

To Backup:

- right click database to which you want to backup
- click `Task`
- and select `BackUp`
- fill-in Name and add the `Destination`

To Restore:

- right click `Databases`
- a popup will appear and click `Restore Database...`

Other Link

- [Backing Up and Restoring How-to Topics (*SQL Server Management Studio*)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189621%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Should the "restore" part be done in the other pc or on my original databse after backing it up?

Comment: yep, restore it on the other pc